# How to set Created pdf's location after generating PDF in html2pdf?

Tags: html2pdf

I have used html2pdf for generating pdf.
It works well.
But it creates files to root folder. I want to save all the pdf's to desired location.

So how to save create pdf to desired location?

Answer (score 1):

You can use path in outout parameter like

```
$html2pdf->Output('/absolut/directory/path/to/file_xxxx.pdf', 'F');
```

EDIT:
be sure: the path is writeable by your service!